# How do I set up and interpret the results of the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test for unit root in SPSS?

Tags: r, statistics, spss

Before doing a multivariate autoregressive analysis I'd like to do an ADF test. My independent variables among others include:

Daily Twitter volume, and two lag variables:

- Daily Twitter volume(t-1)
- Daily Twitter volume(t-2)

As these two lag variables are included in my dataset, I assumed best thing to do is to delete the first two rows of data as missing values are not allowed in this test? Next, a few things are not clear to me:

1. First, it is not clear to me what lag order means when setting up the test. For example, when setting up the ADF test for the variable of Daily Twitter volume(t-1), should I fill in '1' for lag order, as the lag length is 1?
2. Second, I was hoping to be provided with a test statistic (Z (t) scores) and p-value, so I could compare them to the critical values of the ADF test. However, I am only provided with:

   [Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OQaX.png)

   ```
   Time Series Tests for Variable: TW1

   Values

   Test(3)                         Augmented Dickey-Fuller

   Altnernative Hypothesis (3)     Stationary

   P-Value(3)                      0.01

   Note(3)                         p-value smaller than printed p-value

   Truncation Lag(3)               1
   ```

Computations done by R package `tseries`

> Warning message: In adf.test(dta[, 1], altnernative = adfalth,
>   k=adflagorder): p-value smaller than printed p-value

I'm not sure what is meant with the printed p-value, the truncation lag, the warning message and whether or not this outcome is of any value. I hope someone can help me with setting up the test and interpreting the results correctly.

Answer (score 0):

SPSS Statistics currently doesn't offer an augmented Dickey-Fuller test in a native procedure. There is an R-based extension called STATS TSTESTS that you can install through the Extension Hub if you have the R Essentials installed in SPSS Statistics. Output from this would likely be essentially the same as what you're getting in R.

I'm not sure why you want to compare something to critical values when the p value is already provided.